# How to save values from Dynamic Drop Down List into MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, html-select

I have created a dynamic drop down list, now I want to add the value from drop down list into my database. I am displaying 'Category_Name' to the user, and want to store 'Category_ID' in the database. I have written the following code. Kindly check it.

```
 $select_query=          "Select * from category";
    $select_query_run =     mysql_query($select_query);    
    echo "<select name='category'>";
        while   ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
                    {
                         echo "<option value= '$select_query_array['category_id']' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["name"])."</option>";
                    }
                 $selectTag= "</select>";
                 echo $selectTag;
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING) in F:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\insert_product.php on line 50

Comment: echo "<option value= '$select_query_array['category_id']' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["name"])."</option>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change -

```
echo "<option value= '$select_query_array['category_id']' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["name"])."</option>";
```

TO

```
echo "<option value='".$select_query_array['category_id']."'>".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["name"])."</option>";
```

and add last brace as suggested by @bansi if it is not.

Let me know if it fix or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
while   ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
            {
                 echo "<option value= '$select_query_array['category_id']' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["name"])."</option>";
         $selectTag= "</select>";
         echo $selectTag;
```

should be

```
while   ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
            {
                 echo "<option value= '{$select_query_array['category_id']}' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["name"])."</option>";
            }
         $selectTag= "</select>";
         echo $selectTag;
```

You are missing closing brace for the while loop. You are also missing braces around the variable to replace.

Comment: I have updated the query, but still getting the same error message.

Comment: @TahaKirmani You are also missing braces around the variable to replace. fixed that also.